# Variable arguments with mypy: signature of method incompatible with supertype

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I'm not quite sure why mypy is returning the `Signature of "foo" is incompatible with supertype "Base"` error here. The return types and the argument types seem to match up.

```
from typing import NoReturn, Union


class Base():
    def foo(self, *args: str) -> Union[NoReturn, str]:
        raise NotImplementedError


class A(Base):
    def foo(self, x: str) -> str:
        return x
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

**EDIT**
I changed up `A.foo` to this:

```
def foo(self, *args: str) -> str:
    x = args[0]
    return x
```

Now the mypy error disappeared. However, with this implementation, wouldn't the same issue occur where if there's a `NoReturn` in `Base`, the overridden function can only return `str`?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is a little subtle. So I'll explain what each does

```
def foo(self, *args: str) -> Union[NoReturn, str]:
```

`foo` is an instance method of the class `Base` that takes a variable amount of string arguments and returns either `NoReturn` or a `str`.

```
def foo(self, x: str) -> str:
```

`foo` is an instance method of the class `A` that overrides the definition of `foo` in the `Base` class. It takes a single `str` argument and returns a single `str`

What this means is I could call the `Base` version like `foo('bar', 'baz')` but the same call in `A` would throw an error.

Similarly, I can have no return in `Base` while the overridden function call only returns `str`

The issue with this here is that the function has different behavior and type but the same name, which is misleading.

Comment: Sorry, I understand what you're saying. So, I changed up `A.foo` to this:

`def foo(self, *args: str) -> str: \n\t x = args[0] \n\t return x`

Now the mypy error disappeared. However, with this implementation, wouldn't the same issue occur where if there's a `NoReturn` in `Base`, the overridden function can only return `str`?

Comment: Instead of posting in a comment, can you add that to your original question?

Comment: I've added the formatted version of the question to the original post

Answer (score 1):

Without your **EDIT**, you have the issue described by @Skam:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55071593/369009

With the **EDIT**, everything is fine. Think about this code:

```
bs: Base = A() # bs is of type Base
return_value = bs.foo('test') # Return value is of type `Union[NoReturn, str]`
```

When calling `bs.foo`, we expet the return value to be either a `NoReturn` or a `str`. `A` always returns a `str`, but this is fine, since a `str` is also part of the `Union[NoReturn, str]`, so this is always valid. Anyone calling `foo` on the base class has to handle both return types, and `A` just happens to always return only a `str` and never a `NoReturn`.

Only if it were the other way around it would be an issue:
Assuming `A` would return the `Union` and `Base` would return a `str`, then callers of `Base.foo` might suddendly get a `NoReturn` when they expected only a `str`.